# Trying to render @categories from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, view, partial

I am using forem and trying to render a list of all the categories (which is supplied by one controller) and should show up on every page of the forums. The problem is, I am trying to pull @categories from CategoriesController to the sidebar that will be on different pages throughout the site.

Comment: Can you post some code to better explain the problem you are having?

Comment: <%= render :partial =>'forem/forums/sidebar' %>
------- The Partial ----------
<div class="span3">
<div id="forum-sidebar">
  <%= render @categories %>
</div></div>

Answer (score 1):

"Doing It Wrong"

A list of all the categories should come from the Categories model or helper code, not the controller. The controller is for handling incoming HTTP requests, and should not interact with other controllers.

You should put your sidebar in the application layout, and then define `@categories` in a [`before_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in the application controller.

Comment: So you need to put `before_filter` only in controller responsible for forum section.

Comment: How would I got about editing the controller, it's an engine that didn't generate any controllers

Comment: Most of the engines supply some method for putting their code into the app. Which engine?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for using "Presenters".

I agree with @Narfanator; you should pull categories from the Categories model not the controller.  I however do not like to use the before_filter in the application controller unless you want to show categories on all of the pages in your site.

Take a look at this article http://www.derekhammer.com/2012/11/06/a-pattern-for-rails-presenters.  If you like learning via videos, take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?view=comments.  The video gives you a through example on using presenters.  This will greatly clean up your code and simplify your life.